# Self hosted OWIN and urlacl

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, acl, nancy

I've created a self hosted Nancy/SignalR application self-hosted in OWIN using `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener` and `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting`

Things work perfectly fine locally but as soon as I try to use anything but localhost to access the app I get a `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable` error. I can't even access the app using `127.0.0.1` or the machine name.

I've tried adding the port to urlacl using

`http add urlacl http://*:8989/ user=EVERYONE` but doesn't seem to do anything.

here are the OWIN start options that I've tried,

```
var options = new StartOptions
{
    Url = "127.0.0.1",
    App = GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName,
    Port = _configFileProvider.Port
};

var options = new StartOptions
{
    App = GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName,
    Port = _configFileProvider.Port
};
```

Here is [the source code](https://github.com/NzbDrone/NzbDrone/blob/vnext/NzbDrone/Owin/OwinHostController.cs) for the file that starts and stops the server.

Comment: What url did you use in your code?

Comment: @dfowler updated the question with actual code.

Comment: Try changing Url to "*" instead of binding to 127.0.0.1 only.

Comment: Your urlacl should also be + not * afaik

Comment: @stevenrobins when I use + it won't even work for localhost

Comment: @dfowler tried "*" doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

so it turns out you need to pass in a url into `StartOptions` in the same format as the urlacl.

Changing the start options to the code below fixed the problem. now the app is accessible across the network.

```
  var options = new StartOptions("http://*:8989")
  {
      ServerFactory = "Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener"
  };
```

Comment: How does this need to be adapted for SignalR 2 beta?  Url and App are not properties of StartOptions as it shows for me.

Comment: @uosɐſupdated sample code to match the syntax for current version of owin (1.1.0 beta 2)

Comment: Wow. Very very useful :) So many other similar answers out there (mostly talking about IIS Express) but this one actually works.

Comment: And, actually, you don't want to reserve ports with urlacl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293445/http-503-service-is-unavailable-when-trying-to-browse-signalr-hubs has some more information.

Comment: In the end, what worked for me on Server 2012 and Windows 8.1 was to use http://+:9000 (with no urlacls set) and have the port open (on the domain in my case).

Comment: I've been working on this for the past two days and I was so frustrated I wanted to stab a puppy. thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I spend many hours solving similar issue on Windows 8.1.

```
    StartOptions options = new StartOptions();

    options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:9000");
    options.Urls.Add("http://127.0.0.1:9000");
    options.Urls.Add("http://192.168.0.102:9000");
    options.Urls.Add(string.Format("http://{0}:9000", Environment.MachineName));

    WebApp.Start<Startup>(options);
```

I could not listen or was getting 503 error...

If you want to listen on several IP addresses, each address needs its own urlacl record:

Does NOT work:

```
    netsh http>add urlacl http://+:9000/ user=EveryOne
```

OK:

```
    netsh http>add urlacl http://localhost:9000/ user=EveryOne
    netsh http>add urlacl http://127.0.0.1:9000/ user=EveryOne
    etc.
```

After adding reservation for each address individually, everything works fine.

Comment: Adding several IP addresses or URL's also works with new StartOption("http://*:9000/") on Microsoft.Owin.Hosting 3.0.1. and netsh http> add urlacl http://*:9000/, or run your app as admin.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to the info that @kay.one provided I was able to access my self-hosted Web API 2.2 (OWIN/Katana, console app) from the same machine via IP address. However just consolidate it into a simple step-by-step:

1. In `Main` of Program.cs (for console app): `WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://*:8080");`
2. From Windows Command Prompt (run as Administrator) enter `netsh http add urlacl http://*:8080/ user=EVERYONE`
3. Go to *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security* and add an Inbound Rule that opens up TCP port 8080

You should then be able to access from another machine using IP address or computer name.

Disclaimer: I'm not a security expert so I don't know the security implications of doing this.