# SignalR - only works with localhost

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr

So, I have a SignalR self hosted console application and a website running on WAMP. Everything works just fine when I'm using `localhost` as domain-name. Obviously this only works locally.

I want it to work on other computer too. So I have tried to change `localhost` to my local ip, both in the c# console application, and also on the website. The console application crashes when I have my local ip, with the error :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I have also tried to use `*` instead of `localhost` in the console application. Like this:

```
string url = "http://*:8080/servers/2/";
```

Same goes there, it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Console application code:

```
namespace SignalRSelfHost
{        
    class Program
    {    
        public static IPAddress ipAd { get; set; }
        public static TcpListener myList { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.

            string url = "http://localhost:8080/servers/2/";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }                
        }            
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true

                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);

        }
    }
}
```

And my website's code:

```
<input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>

<!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/servers/<?php echo $server->row()->id; ?>/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/servers/<?php echo $server->row()->id; ?>/signalr";
            //Set the hubs URL for the connection
            $.connection.hub.url = url;

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li>' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            //$('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            //$('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you able to run from browser debug? I want to know where it is failing, to invoke signalR or something else? As per current error it looks like .NET library invocation error.

Comment: `TargetInvocationException` should have a non-null InnerException which should tell you more details about the error you are seeing. Post the full exception details otherwise it can be just anything.

Comment: Like this? http://pastebin.com/c9KnKzR7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it by running the program as administrator.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22972905/2381899 This one doesn't require running as administrator.

Comment: This fixed my issue! I have been searching for hours regarding why SignalR was working locally for me but not remotely. Thank you for the simple workaround!