# Self Hosted OWIN Web Service - Not Listening

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api, owin

**Issue:**
When running the Web API, self hosted using OWIN, All HTTP connections are refused (no status code returned), but only on a particular test machine, not on any other machines (they all work fine).

**Sample code:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    var options = new StartOptions();
    options.Urls.Add($"http://+:{port}");
    using(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup>(options)){
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Additional info:**
- Running as admin eliminates urlacl as being the cause of the problem. so url port reservations are not the issue.
- Tried using various port numbers to eliminate port number conflicts.
- Making the service use + url prefix in it's baseurl eliminates other listeners intercepting the request.
- Calling localhost (and other hostnames that resolve to 127.0.0.1) eliminates firewall.
- Code has been run with debugger, no exceptions there.
- There is no entry when i run netstat for that port. (The working machines show an enrty.)

**Question:**
I'd like to know what the issue is with this particular machine, and how to resolve it.
What do you suggest in order to achieve this?

**Related Questions that did not answer my question (or were not applicable):**
[Self-hosted OWIN project; http://localhost:8080 won't work, http://+:8080 does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667946/self-hosted-owin-project-http-localhost8080-wont-work-http-8080-does)
[HTTP 503 Service is unavailable when trying to browse signalr/hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293445/http-503-service-is-unavailable-when-trying-to-browse-signalr-hubs)
[Self hosted OWIN and urlacl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642651/self-hosted-owin-and-urlacl)
[Owin selfhost: using netsh to add an urlAcl seems to cause 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497970/owin-selfhost-using-netsh-to-add-an-urlacl-seems-to-cause-503)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She solution turns out to be something seemingly unrelated.
In the Startup class, it was trying to enter A duplicate database entry and throw an exception.
However this exception was wrapped within a TargetInvocationException that was already being handled (and incorrectly consumed).
The error handling was updated and all systems are now listening on the specified port correctly.