# Cannot use multiple options OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I've got a small problem regarding a server hosted with OWIN. I'm trying to make it accessible to the local network which means I have to add a few extra options:

```
// Start OWIN host 
        StartOptions options = new StartOptions();
        options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:4004");
        //options.Urls.Add("http://127.0.0.1:4004");
        //options.Urls.Add(string.Format("http://{0}:4004", Environment.MachineName));
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(options))
        {

            // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/text"));

        }
```

Now the problem is, if I uncomment the second line:

```
options.Urls.Add("http://127.0.0.1:4004");
```

I'll get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

Can someone help me out? It's weird that I can only use localhost, and not my ip.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642651/self-hosted-owin-and-urlacl your code looks fine. Are there any more details in exceptions? Like inner exception or something.

Comment: @Mino yes, there is an inner exception: "Acces is denied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that there is no admin rights. I get an acces denied inner exception. With the use of this in a manifest application file I've made the error go away :)

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```