# OWIN error while connecting via ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, owin

I try to login my selfhosted website via ip address and its dont working(using owin) i tried using this [Self hosted OWIN and urlacl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642651/self-hosted-owin-and-urlacl) but it still not working this is my code:

Main:

```
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://*:9000/";
            // Start OWIN host
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:9000/api/check").Result;

                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                Console.ReadLine(); // Keeps the host from disposing immediately
            }
        }
```

SetUp:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API contained in the class Startup, which is additionally specified as the type parameter in WebApplication.Start
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for Self-Host
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

and controler:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
namespace Owin_Testing
{
    public class CheckController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><h1>Working</h1></html>");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

When i try localhost:9000 or 127.0.0.1:9000 but with ip its still dont work(its console application)
i made tcp inbound role on port 9000 and tried on my rdp too

Comment: I thought OWIN only worked with names and not raw IP addresses?  If that's true then you can add an entry to the HOSTS file to make 127.0.0.1 to a name and connect to that.

Comment: maby its possible but if its only with names so u have any suggestion for something that would work with ip address?